# Puzzle: Seeking a book to reveal secret of numbers

Tags: mathematics, knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle

The following numbers came upon me after waking from a deep sleep.

2 3 14 6-7

23140 6

3 14 15 9-11

3141 5-9

23146

Is there a code book that can help me? I'm sure I'll know when I find the book.

And is there a button on my calculator that will convert these numbers?

While I thought on these things an angel appeared unto me in a dream, and revealed these extra markings. These might provide additional clues.

> b2 c3 v14 w6-7
> v23140 w6
> b3 c14 v15 w9-11
> v3141 w5-9
> v23146

I'm looking for the book, the decoded message, the button, what I am, and to know whether I have a rational basis for functioning.

Comment: Are first and last numbers in the intended way?

Comment: @ACB Yes, they are.

Comment: Has a correct answer been given? If so, please don't forget to $\color{green}{\checkmark \small\text{Accept}}$ it.  If not, a response to the answerer to help steer them in the right direction might be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code book you are looking for is:

> The KJV Bible

Reasoning:

> The notation style and use of the word “angel” suggest that the code book we seek is the Bible, likely the King James Version as a traditional authoritative English source.

Let’s investigate the clues:
b2 c3 v14 w6-7

> Book 2 (Exodus), Chapter 3, Verse 14, Words 6-7:
>  **“I am”** (yes, from the famous verse)
>  (side note; this number and some others are similar to e^pi - credit ACB).

v23140 w6

> Similarly, Malachi 4:2, word 6 (this being the 23,140th verse in the Bible overall)
>  **“that”**

b3 c14 v15 w9-11

> Leviticus 14:15, 9-11
>  **“log of oil”**
>  (side note; this number and the next are similar to pi)

v3141 w5-9

> Leviticus 14:29, 5-9 (this being the 3,141st verse in the Bible overall)
>  **“the oil that is in”**

v23146

> Matthew 1:1
>  **“The book of the generation of Jesus Christ, the son of David, the son of Abraham.”**

So we have:
The code book:

> The KJV Bible

The message:

> “I am that log of oil, the oil that is in the book of the generation of Jesus Christ, the son of David, the son of Abraham.”

The button on the calculator:

> I'd thought the log button, used on a numeric equivalent of 'oil', since you are the "log of oil", but per op not correct.
>  The obvious alternative possibility is the **ln** button, which is in line with the numbers used in the puzzle. We have pi and e^pi in the puzzle; ln(e^pi)=pi, which is notable.
>  I thought maybe *OIL=ENERGY=E*, so we have *log of oil = log of e = log e* (a stretch, doesn't quite make sense), or possibly OIL sounds a little bit like EULER (credit Rubio), but also a bit of a stretch. But by process of elimination, and bearing in mind the numbers used, perhaps the button on the calculator is indeed the **"ln" button**.

What you are, and whether you have a rational basis for functioning:

> If you are the log of Euler, or "Euler's log", I suppose no, you have no rational basis for functioning, as you operate based on the number e, which is irrational.

Comment: rot13(Gur ahzoref ner eryngrq gb cv naq rkc(cv).)

Comment: Correct message.

Comment: rot13(Ybt bs bvy...re .... fubhyq or ybt bs Rhyre?) :)

Comment: fb jung vf gur rknpg ohggba naq gur onfr?